# Weird Patchy Cycles Render when I use Principal Volume & Light

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, volumetrics

I used a spotlight to make a projector based on a tutorial I used (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=adahnQCqmw0) and I keep getting these patchy results even when I render to 1000 levels in Cycles. I'll include my render/light settings, this can't be as simple as just turning up the levels which kinda helps.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have a denoiser on?

Comment: @Benus yea
Radius:10px
Strength:0.5
Feature Strength:0.5
Relative Filter: Off
Diffuse: Direct & Indirect
Glossy: Direct & Indirect
Transmission: Direct & Indirect

Comment: @Benus Render: NLM